# how to bind button is enable property to a enum in wpf

Tags: wpf, listview

i am using listView grouping based on an enum which {Updated and not Updated}.  In my case, their is a button to call update I just want to disable if rows are in an updated group. See in the images.

[image]
The list that is present in updated section I want that the button should be disabled. I am using an example found in [Here](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/listview-control/listview-grouping/)

Comment: You might be interested in [Converters](https://www.wpftutorial.net/valueconverters.html)

Comment: yes i already found solution but anyways that is also helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IsEnabled={Binding ProperyNameOnYourViewModel, Mode=OneWay}
```

That will work assuming 1) your VM implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and triggers appropriate event at the appropriate moment (typically, property's setter is responsible for that); 2) your control itself knows how to react on `IsEnabled=false` visually, i.e. changes color or whatever you like it to do.

Since you got an enum rather than bool, the easiest way to stick to the solution I've suggest is by extending your VM with yet another property, which recomputes boolean flag all the time. Then you might invoke `PropertyChanged` event not from your `bool` property (to which `IsEnabled` is actually bound), but from the `enum` property such that whenever it changes, WPF gets notified that boolean property has changed as well.

Otherwise, solve the problem with help of converters, which requires a lot more code.